# Group 1 not matching up per regex

Tags: java, regex

I want the following:

-- Input--

```
keep this

      keep this too
  ------ Remove Below ------
  remove all of this
```

to become:

-- Output --

```
keep this

      keep this too
```

However, I cannot figure out how to match everything up until "------ Remove Below ------" so that I can group things and remove everything but the above expected output.

```
    String text = "keep this\n       \n"
            + "      keep this too\n  ------ Remove Below ------\n  remove all of this\n";
    Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.*)(-+)(.*)Remove Below(.*)(-+)(.*)$",
            Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        int count = m.groupCount();
        String g0 = m.group(0);
        String g1 = m.group(1);  // contains "keep this\n    \n    keep this too\n -----"
        String g2 = m.group(2);
        //
        // How can I group correctly to arrive at above expected -- Output --??
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your regex `non-greedy`:

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)(-+)(.*?)Remove Below(.*?)(-+)(.*)$", 
                                  Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Also `Pattern.MULTILINE` isn't needed in your case.

Now `m.group(1)` will give you:

```
keep this\n       \n      keep this too\n
```

Comment: What does that (-+) indicates . Is it - followed by +?

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks for the reply. Yes, that worked. Can you explain a bit on how the "-----" portion was showing up in group1?  Is the the case of greedy backtracking?

Comment: That was the case of `greedy matching`. You had `(.*)` which matching this text that you want to match and all but one hyphen. Next group `(-+)` was just matching `single hyphen`. With non-greedy quantifier `(-+)` matches all hyphens and group 1 just gets the part you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
"^(.*?)(-+)(.*)Remove Below(.*)(-+)(.*)$"
```

would also do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use check the index of "------ Remove Below ------" and then take the substring before that index or
Split string into a string array with each line as one array item

```
String[] split = s.split("\n");
```

Loop through this array and construct a string until the item matches ------ Remove Below ------

```
String result="";
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            if(!str[i].contains(" Remove Below ")){
                result = result.concat(str[i]);
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
```